# jQuery .animate going off page

Tags: jquery

I am using the .animate function and was wondering how to make users not be able to scroll down to ugly parts of the .animate going off the page. Any Help Would Be Awesome!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If possible, can post `html`, `css`, `js` ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is set the body height in css.

```
body{
   height:100px;
 }
```